# How to calculate mean and standard deviation of exponential values in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I need to calculate the mean and std.dev of a list of -ve exponential values using python. Using the usual np.mean(list_of_values) doesn't seem to give me the correct answer.

My list has values like list_of_values = [8.581952e-309, 1.304333e-320, 0.000000e+00, 6.787212e-611, ...] and is approx 10k in length.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some numbers are 10^300 bigger than others. That 0.000000e+00 is going to dominate everything else. How are you validating the correct value?

Comment: That's right. Even I was wondering along those lines. That is why I want to use std.dev/variance to estimate the spread of the values. What would be your suggestion?